# Trigger event on Here maps externally

Tags: javascript, events, triggers, click, here-api

I have a Here map similar to this one from it's API documentation:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/open-infobubble

Now in Google Maps, there's a function that we can use to trigget any event externally - `google.maps.event.trigger`.

How would I go about doing the same with Here maps? Specifically, I want to open an infobubble by clicking on a link on the same page (but not within the map itself)?

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically trigger an event on a marker with the method `dispatchEvent` on any instance of `H.map.Marker`.

Given a reference to a marker, this would look like this:

```
myMarker.dispatchEvent('tap');
```

The event name is *'tap'* as you can see from the example that you linked, on the line where we add the event listener which opens the info bubble:

```
group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    // opens info bubble
}
```

**[API reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-marker.html#h-map-marker__dispatchevent)**